# How does IIS Express get custom domains routed to it?

Tags: iis-express

If I add this to a site in applicationhost.config:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:15408:helloworld" />
```

Then behind the scenes, how does the OS know to route the domain 'helloworld' to Express?

Answer (score 1):

The OS does not know. Yourself should set up DNS and anything else to fulfill that.

Comment: So the DNS resolves to localhost which routes to IIS Express which matches the host header and port to a binding?